# TM hydride chemical shift

Tags: coordination-compounds, nmr-spectroscopy

Why is the chemical shift for hydrides in TM complexes so strongly shielded, to the point where it's negative?

Initially, I thought it was because hydrides are $\ce{H-}$, but isn't the charge meaningless once it coordinates to a metal centre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially answer this question yourself. The chemical shifts of transition metal hydrides are often largely negative because they are highly shielded. That's what chemical shifts are a measure of - the amount of shielding from the external magnetic field. A very small hydride nucleus buried in a great big fluffy cloud of d-shell electrons of a transition metal is incredibly highly shielded from the base magnetic field.

The negative number of the chemical shift is arbitrary; what is relevant is that chemical shifts to the right are more shielded, and those to the left are less shielded.

Read the information about chemical shifts on [this great online resource](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/05-hmr-02-delta.htm).